# InstallShield Limited edition "Shortcut" options to Users?

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield, setup-deployment, installshield-2012

I am using Install shield limited edition 2012 to create a set up project  from my WPF application. I know we can  predefine  shortcuts using Application shortcuts menu.

Can I add the following options for the users to select the shortcuts while installing the setup?

```
Add shortcut to Start List
Add shortcut to desktop
Add shortcut to task bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these options using Install shield is possible in premier or professional editions. But I don't think these features are available in Limited Edition, as the name suggests. Because dialog and script editors are not available in [Limited edition](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/promolanding/10909.htm).